# Are the creation and solution of CTF exercise welcomed here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen this question on the Close Votes queue:

[Why does the run level change automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/q/375632/169736)

At first, when I saw the title it picked my curiosity, but then reading OP's comment:

> Thanks for the link, I part of what I am looking for, any idea **how would my friend be able to find the problem?** also **what are some other methods to sabotage the system?**

makes me remember about a [question on U&L](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1416/41104) about the same topic but here there isn't... so, what's our response to those kind of questions?

Answer (score 3):

Answer them.

Strip away the "why they're asking" and there's a perfectly valid question here. I'm not concerned that if we allow this 99% of our questions will suddenly become "How should I break my Ubuntu install?"

It's a *bit* specific but so is a lot of stuff. It's also fairly educational and just leaving it alone isn't hurting anybody. You never know, you might even learn something from it being answered.

---

That covers the creation. The [U&L meta question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-solving-a-ctf-too-localized) is more about solving a manually crafted issue and yes, that's probably an overly localised issue. But there's still scope for it being a valuable debugging process.

I'm not going to say they're all bad without having seen a single one here.

Comment: Well, that wasn't very good here http://askubuntu.com/q/233426/169736

Comment: @Braiam That one's a little less informative (and a bit more "do my homework") than the original example which was asking about how something worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a solution to this problem.  I have had several installs that  I left open to attack and I would dismantle viruses on them. Dropping firewall rules and having a sandbox program to play in I dismantled several attacks, but again I failed to thwart attackers; but in all I learned a little and had a little fun.

A sandbox partition would be better for this, a sandbox works like a virtual linux o/s which can be broken in to or broken, but it is an experimental Ubuntu, and so who cares?

And then there is "deep freeze linux", deep freeze would return the whole operating system from the bios up to boot condition removing all changes made in the name of computer science.

One caveat: If you log in to askubuntu and infect their computers, you will probably be banned at least. That isn't a good ending for anybody.

Look up "DeepFreeze Linux," and "virtual machine ubuntu" and check out [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1398659) and [this program](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/ofris-deep-freeze-like-application-for.html) for a sample of what  is and isn't allowed, I mean welcome.